# Как изменить значение рассчитываемого из множителей числа, отображаемого на label, при изменении значений множителей на slider?

Tags: swift, slider, label

Делаю ипотечный калькулятор.

1. есть два ползунка: 
   -а. величина процентной ставки 
   -б. количество лет ипотеки
2. есть текстовое поле - сумма кредита
3. есть лэйбл - ежемесячный платеж, который рассчитывается исходя из входных данных: 1а, 1б и 2.

текстовое поле имеет метод editing change, при изменении суммы кредита текст лэйбла "ежемесячный платеж" автоматически меняется/пересчитывается.

как сделать так, чтобы "ежемесячный платеж" пересчитывался при передвижении ползунков "срока кредита" и "процентной ставки"?

пробовал делать наблюдатели свойств, не получилось

```css
[![скриншот моего сториборд][1]][1]



    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var percentLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sliderPercent: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var termLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sliderTerm: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldSumm: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountLabel: UILabel!
        
    @IBAction func textChangedSumm(_ sender: UITextField) {
        if let summ = Int(sender.text!) {
        self.amountLabel.text = "\((Double(summ) * Double(sliderPercent.value/1200) * Double(pow(1 + Double(sliderPercent.value/1200), Double(sliderTerm.value*12))) / (Double(pow(1 + Double(sliderPercent.value/1200), Double(sliderTerm.value*12))) - 1)).rounded()) руб"
        } else {
        self.amountLabel.text = "0"
        }
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        percentLabel.text = "\(sliderPercent.value.rounded()) %"
        amountLabel.text = "0"
        termLabel.text = "\(Int(sliderTerm.value)) лет"
        self.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если ручь о слушателях событий, то для `UISlider` добавляем слушатель на `valueChanged` в коде или в сториборд

```
sliderPercent.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    // пересчет c учетом sender.value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

я написал функцию и вставил ее в соответствующие методы 2-х слайдеров

```
 func changeAmount() -> String {
    var amountValue = ""
    let percentValue = sliderPercent.value.rounded()
    let termValue = sliderTerm.value.rounded()
           if let summ = Int(textFieldSumm.text!) {
                amountValue = "\(Int(Double(summ) * Double(percentValue/1200) * Double(pow(1 + Double(percentValue/1200), Double(termValue*12))) / (Double(pow(1 + Double(percentValue/1200), Double(termValue*12))) - 1))) руб"
           } else {
            self.amountLabel.text = "0 руб"
           }
           return amountValue
       }
```